On duality of a space of functions.
I was reading up some old courses I once took and noticed a similar type of reasoning between biduals of vector spaces and the Gelfand representation of commutative (unital) C$^*$-algebras. I was wondering whether there’s a deeper connection between both dualities or even a general underlying principle.
That said, let’s make this question more concrete.
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space. The dual space is $V^*=\text{Hom}_{K}(V,K)$ consisting of all linear functionals on $V$. It is easy to show that the map
$$\text{ev}\colon V\rightarrow V^{**}: v\mapsto \text{ev}_v$$ where for $f\in V^*$, $\text{ev}_v(f)=f(v)$ is a linear map and an isomorphism in case $V$ is finite dimensional. In particular, I want to note that each $\text{ev}_v$ is a linear functional on $V$ and every linear functional on $V$ is of this form. This means that given $V^*$, you can reconstruct $V$ by simply considering all linear functionals (or evaluations) on $V^*$.
Now let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. In some sense, $C(X)$ can be seen as already being a ‘dual space’. Each element of $C(X)$ is already a function to the ground field $\mathbb{C}$. Off course, it’s not linear but it sees the topological structure of $X$ as it continuous.
The beautiful Gelfand representation theorem states that one can reconstruct $X$ as the the maximal ideal space, or equivalently, as the character space of $C(X)$. Here, a character is an algebra morphism $C(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Equivalently, a character is a multiplicative linear functional. For $C(X)$, one can show that any character actually corresponds to the evaluation at a point of $X$.
So in both examples, one goes from a ‘dual’ space to the ‘underlying’ space by considering those linear functionals that actually correspond to evaluations at a point. In the finite dimensional vector space setting, no further assumption on the linear functionals is required, in the unital commutative C$^*$-algebra case, the functionals are also multiplicative (and automatically continuous of norm one).
Both feel somewhat similar and I was wondering if there’s more here than meets the eye. I’m not looking for a categorical description of duality but more for a general way of obtaining duality for spaces of functions.
Perhaps there’s nothing to it, it’s not weird that if $F(X)$ is a set of functions on $X$ that is large enough and compatible with the structure of $X$, that evaluation at some $x$ can be identified with $x$. So perhaps my question is whether this last statement can be made more precise?

It's a duplicate question. You can find the answer with site search or by going directly to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizing+object and https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality

I will add the category theory tag since it's exactly what category theory is made for. Providing a general framework for these kind of equivalences.

Hmm, that’s not really the answer I was looking for. As I said, I’m not looking for a categorical description of duality. I’m more looking for guidelines on what properties you should put on your functionals to get that they correspond to evaluations in variuous settings.

The first link exactly explains this.

I might be misreading the first link, but to me it seems you already start with the duality and structures from the get-go. It seems like a proper framework for duality, but doesn’t tell you how to construct duality? Given a certain space of functions, how do I know the correct category it belongs to?

I’ll interpret the question as asking, given some space $V$, if there is some general guiding principle as to how to define a “double dual” of $V$ s.t. $V$ is naturally isomorphic to this “double dual”. It is too vague to admit any precise answer, but generally, the requirement is continuity - instead of thinking of the “full double dual” (like the full double dual space $V^{\ast\ast}$ in case $V$ is a vector space or the space of all functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$ in case $V = C(X)$), you should impose the “weak$^\ast$ topology” on the dual space and only consider those elements that are “weak$^\ast$ continuous”.
This is precisely what happened for topological vector spaces $V$: if you impose on $V^\ast$ the weak$^\ast$ topology $\sigma(V^\ast, V)$, then a linear functional $V^\ast \to \mathbb{K}$ is continuous iff it is the evaluation functional at some element of $V$. In other word, the double dual $V^{\ast\ast}$ (where when taking the second dual space we meant the topological dual w.r.t. the weak$^\ast$ topology) is naturally isomorphic to $V$. This continuity condition is unnecessary for finite-dimensional $V$, as any linear functional on a finite-dimensional space is automatically continuous w.r.t. any locally convex Hausdorff topology, in particular the weak$^\ast$ topology.
The case where $V = C(X)$ is self-evident in this regard - what you started with is exactly all continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$. But here is the connection to this idea of taking weak$^\ast$ topology: the topology on $X$ is exactly the weak$^\ast$ topology on the corresponding evaluation functionals. Indeed, $X \subset V^\ast$ is a topological embedding, when the latter is equipped with the weak$^\ast$ topology. In this way, Gelfand duality sort of starts with the observation that $V = V^{\ast\ast}$ when $V^\ast$ is equipped with the weak$^\ast$ topology. It’s just this fact, coupled with the additional observation that, when restricting to a specific subset of $V^\ast$, namely the (nonzero) multiplicative linear functionals, $V = V^{\ast\ast} \subset \{f: V^\ast \to \mathbb{C}\}$ restricts to an algebra which separates points, so by Stone-Weierstrass it must be exactly the algebra of continuous functions on the space of (nonzero) multiplicative linear functionals.
One more example of this idea might be the Stone duality for Boolean algebras. The Stone space $S(A)$ of a Boolean algebra $A$ consists of ultrafilters on $A$, which are exactly functions $A \to \{0, 1\}$ which respects the Boolean algebra structure, so it’s sort of the “dual space” of $A$. The topology imposed on the Stone space is exactly the weak$^\ast$ topology, if the Stone space is understood as a space of functions. And the original Boolean algebra can retrieved exactly as the “double dual”, namely, it consists exactly of the functions $S(A) \to \{0, 1\}$ which are continuous under the topology on $S(A)$, namely the weak$^\ast$ topology, equipped with the pointwise Boolean algebra operations.

This seems to be more what I had in mind. Indeed weak * continuity seems to be the requirement for the functionals. Is there also a know duality for differentiable functions on some space/manifold?

@Mathematician42 I’m not an expert in geometry, but IIRC, for a compact smooth manifold $M$, you can reconstruct $M$ and its smooth structure from the inclusion of algebras $C^\infty(M)\subset C(M)$. It’s sort of boring though, since this is not an abstract characterization of the inclusion $C^\infty(M)\subset C(M)$, only that if you already know the inclusion is of this form, then you can get $M$ back. If you want an abstract characterization with a duality theory, this is far more elaborate and is known as spectral triples. See https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2088.

@Mathematician42 Even then this requires some additional structures, as a spectral triple also encodes a Riemannian structure and a spin structure, and the manifold has to be oriented for this work. In any case, this is definitely far more complicated than just considering weak$^\ast$ continuity, which in general only works if the objects in question are just “topological” and/or dually, “algebraic”.
